# How to access all images uri in node's field in custom module?

Tags: nodes, 8, uri

I already know I can get an url for field of node this way:

```
$src = file_create_url($node->get('name_of_image_field')->entity->uri->value);
```

The problem is, my field `name_of_image_field` has multiple images. **How to access them all?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
$img_urls = array();
foreach ($node->field_image as $item) {
  if ($item->entity) {
    $img_urls[] = $item->entity->url();
  }
}
```

Then all `field_image` image urls available in `$img_urls` variable.

Comment: Maybe you should remove the kint() function, since it requires devel, or make a note about that in your answer.

Comment: The kint line should be `$image_urls[] = $item->entity->url();` than he can do another `foreach ($image_urls as $key => $url) {...` to get the individual urls.

Comment: Note: method url() have use function file_create_url(). don't use again.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I needed. Also up-voted Jaypan answer because I didn't know which one was first.

Answer (score 4):

```
$srcs = array();
// Loop through the Languages
foreach ($node->field_image as $items) {
  // Loop through each item in each language
  foreach($items as $item) {
    if ($item->entity) {
      // Set the path as the key, to prevent duplicates
      $srcs[$item->entity->url()] = $item->entity->url();
    }
  }
}
```

$srcs will contain an array web-accessible URLs for every image attached to every language of the node.

Comment: I don't think is good code. Do do you try see code in method [url()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!file!src!Entity!File.php/class/File/8.2.x). `public function url($rel = 'canonical', $options = array()) {
    return file_create_url($this->getFileUri());
  }`.  file_create_url call 4 time in one statements. Very bad.

Comment: You're correct, I've edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use:

```
$delta = 0;
$file_item_list = $node->field_image;

if ($file_item_list && $file_item_list->offsetExists($delta)) {
$image_url = file_create_url($file_item_list->offsetGet($delta)->get('entity')->getValue()->getFileUri());
}
```

Check [Class FileFieldItemList](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21src%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldType%21FileFieldItemList.php/class/FileFieldItemList/8.2.x) for more details.